# Data Loss in JPEG/PNG resizing

Tags: php, image

I've adapted this code that I found. It resizes .jpg and .png images, and maintains alpha layers.

When I resize an image, however, the reduction in file size is far more than I had anticipated. This isn't a problem for me, as I cannot see with my eyes any degradation or data loss.

What is causing the huge compression of the file, and if I ever needed to, how can I avoid it?

```
function thumbnail($image, $width, $height, $target) {

if($image[0] != "/") { // Decide where to look for the image if a full path is not given
    if(!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) { // Try to find image if accessed directly from this script in a browser
        $image = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].implode("/", (explode('/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], -1)))."/".$image;
    } else {
        $image = implode("/", (explode('/', $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], -1)))."/".$image;
    }
} else {
    $image = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$image;
}
$image_properties = getimagesize($image);
$image_width = $image_properties[0];
$image_height = $image_properties[1];
$image_ratio = $image_width / $image_height;
$type = $image_properties["mime"];

if(!$width && !$height) {
    $width = $image_width;
    $height = $image_height;
}
if(!$width) {
    $width = round($height * $image_ratio);
}
if(!$height) {
    $height = round($width / $image_ratio);
}

if($type == "image/jpeg") {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
} elseif($type == "image/png") {
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $thumb = imagecreatefrompng($image);
} else {
    return false;
}

$temp_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagealphablending($temp_image, false);
imagesavealpha($temp_image,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($temp_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($temp_image, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
imagecopyresampled($temp_image, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image_width, $image_height);
//$thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
//imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $temp_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
if($type == "image/jpeg") {
    imagejpeg($temp_image, 'img/'.$target.'.jpg');
} else {
    imagepng($temp_image,'img/'.$target.'.png');
}



imagedestroy($temp_image);
//imagedestroy($thumbnail);
```

}

Comment: Provide some hard data in numbers to substantiate your claim.

Comment: These are GD library functions. I believe it can be done very easily in [Image Magick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Comment: You might try adding the `quality` parameter to "imagejpg"/"imagepng":  `imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )`  http://us1.php.net/imagejpeg

Comment: compression algorithms usually take all the colours used in an image, and creates a map of some sort. If you reduced the size of the image, chances are that the # of colours you have on your image is now reduced, which would reduce the size of the colour map. And if your image was originally very colourful, the reduction would be more noticable.

Comment: @deceze I had an image that was 3400 x 2200 px and 4.4MB resized to 1920 x 1280 and is now only 352KB. I had expected the new file to be around 1.2MB.

Comment: 4.4MB for that size sounds pretty large, the smaller one sounds about right intuitively. Maybe your original images contained a lot of meta data or are virtually not compressed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As showdev commented, both `imagejpeg()` and `imagepng()` accept a third optional parameter for the image quality. For `imagejpeg()` it runs from 0 to 100 and defaults to 75), for `imagepng()` it is from 0 to 9 and defaults to 6.

Also, 4.4Mb is a really big size for a ~2.4Mpx image. It problably contains a lot of metadata and most of it -like Photoshop thumbsnails- is not preserved when you do an `imagecopyresampled()` with PHP's GD library.

You should also run one of your test images through a lossless compression program like JStrip (http://davidcrowell.com/jstrip/), to check how much it weights without the bloat.